# How can I get all folders that contain images with the Google Drive API?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

The way I am currently doing this is to get a list of all files that contain "/image" in their mimeType and saving all the unique folder IDs that they are in. This is horribly inefficient.  I was hoping there was a query I could specify in the request that would do the same, but cannot figure it out.  I am using straight JavaScript to do the XMLHttp requests.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list with your mime-type query and run that for each folder. Which approach is more efficient will obv depend on your ratio of folders to files, and whether you already have a cache of folder ids.

Answer (score 0):

It currently isn't possible to search for folders based upon their contents (see [search query documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters)). You can optimize your process some by setting the `fields` parameter to `items/parents/id`, eliminating the fetching and transmission of unused fields.