# how to get multiple image types in google drive api in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-drive-realtime-api

I've this

```
$opt = array('q'=>"mimeType = 'image/jpeg' and name contains '".$file."'")
```

that only fetches images of type jpeg. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
$opt = array('q'=>"mimeType = 'image/*' and name contains '".$file."'")
```

and fetch images of all kind. Hope you got the idea. Thanks

Comment: well, did you actually use that 'image/*' wildcard filter to see if it works? seems legit.

Comment: Yup I've tried. didn't work! gives no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the wildcard * doesn't return all, use the "or" instead and take the long route:

```
mimeType = 'image/jpg' or mimeType = 'image/png' or mimeType = 'image/bmp'
```

You get the idea. this works.

It was also [mentioned by Eric Koledala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28965870/6143482) google engineer, that this is not supported as of now. So use the workaround.

Comment: that's what i thought would work but wasn't sure, thx for confirming.

Comment: btw, i've a folder in gdrive which has around 2k files. but hitting on api only returns 100 of them. any idea?

Comment: you're doing it right. you just need a nextPageToken to access the other 1.9k files. it can only display 100 at a time.

Comment: hey, can you go through the link and help me on my another related question, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074917/can-you-tell-me-whats-wrong-with-this-google-drive-api-call-function-in-php

Comment: lemme check later. i'll prolly do it in JS tho