# can you tell me what's wrong with this google drive API call function in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-drive-android-api

I've got this code to run and fetch images from my drive. But i'm running into a problem every time I run this code.

```
  function listF() {

    $result = array();
    $tok = array();
    $nextPageToken = NULL;
  do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
      if ($nextPageToken) {
        $parameters['pageToken'] = $nextPageToken;
        $parameters['q'] = "mimeType='image/jpeg' or mimeType='image/png'";
      }
      $files = $this->service->files->listFiles($parameters);
      $tok[] = $nextPageToken;
      $result = array_merge($tok, $result, $files->getFiles());
      $nextPageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      $nextPageToken = NULL;
    }
  } while ($nextPageToken);
  return $result;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
An error occurred: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "pageToken"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

It doesn't really seem illegitimate to me. Perhaps you might able to find the bug. Thanks

Comment: `"location": "pageToken"` - sounds like `pageToken` was the parameter with the invalid value. Have you checked what the corresponding variable contains …?

Comment: In your code, you are defining `$nextPageToken = NULL;`. Hence your condition `if ($nextPageToken)` never worked. And so is the error you received, i.e., the pageToken value provided is invalid.

Comment: @Chinmayjain it's intentionally null so that it won't go into the if statement as there won't be any nextPageToken until "$nextPageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();" pops.

Comment: try displaying the value of $nextPageToken before the call to listFiles. I suspect your `if ($nextPageToken) {` is true when it should be false. Also the ` $parameters['q']` should not be inside your if block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer your `nextPageToken` problem using Javascript, just take note of the logic.
I have two listFile() functions which are identical. One executes at initial load, after loading the page, it shows the first 10 of my 100 files. The other executes each time a button is clicked.

**First function** to display the inital 10 files.

```
//take note of this variable
  var nextToken ;
  function listFiles() {
    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      'pageSize': 10,
      'fields': "*"
    }).then(function(response) {

          //assign the nextPageToken to a variable to be used later
          nextToken = response.result.nextPageToken;
          // do whatever you like here, like display first 10 files in web page
          // . . .
        });
      }
```

**Second function:**
This function is triggered by click of a button named "Next Page" which displays the succeeding files from 11 to N.

```
 function gotoNextPage(event) {
          gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            'pageSize': 10,
            'fields': "*",
            'pageToken': nextToken
          }).then(function(response) {
            //assign new nextPageToken to make sure new files are displayed
            nextToken = response.result.nextPageToken;
            //display batch of file results in the web page
            //. . .          
          });
  }
```

Comment: hey, i'm getting an error on the second search. problem in token. getting it, but api tells that its wrong.

Comment: managed to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402545/google-drive-js-api-nextpagetoken-invalid/47402918#47402918
google sux (

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the nextPageToken will be ruled invalid unless you include the exact same query field (q) in the subsequent requests that was included in the initial request.

```
var files = []
var nextToken;
gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    'q': "mimeType='image/jpeg' or mimeType='image/png'",   
    'pageSize': 10,
    'fields': 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
}).then(function(response) {
    nextToken = response.result.nextPageToken;
    files.push(...response.result.files)
    while (nextToken) {
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            'nextPage': nextToken,
            'q': "mimeType='image/jpeg' or mimeType='image/png'",   
            'pageSize': 10,
            'fields': 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
        }).then(function(response) {
            nextToken = response.result.nextPageToken;
            files.push(...response.result.files)
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A V3 tested solution.  This will handle large sets (greater then 1000) by handling pagination:

```
function GetFiles()
{

    $options =
    [
        'pageSize' => 1000,
        'supportsAllDrives' => true,
        'fields' => "files(id, mimeType, name), nextPageToken"
    ];

    $files = [];
    $pageToken = null;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            if ($pageToken !== null)
            {
                $options['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
            }

            $response = $this->service->files->listFiles($options);

            $files = array_merge($files, $response->files);
            $pageToken = $response->getNextPageToken();
        }
        catch (Exception $exception)
        {
            $message = $exception->getMessage();
            echo "Error: $message\r\n";
            $pageToken = null;
        }
    } while ($pageToken !== null);

    return $files;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google Drive V3 PHP API is not as copiously documented as V2.

I found no simple PHP examples utilizing `pageToken` for the V3 API, so I am providing this one:

```php
 $parameters = array();
 $parameters['q'] = "mimeType='image/jpeg' or mimeType='image/png'";
 $parameters['fields'] = "files(id,name), nextPageToken";
 $parameters['pageSize'] = 100;
 $files = $google_drive_service->files->listFiles($parameters);

 /* initially, we're not passing a pageToken, but we need a placeholder value */
 $pageToken = 'go';

 while ($pageToken != null) {
     if (count($files->getFiles()) == 0) {
        echo "No files found.\n";
     } 
     else {
             foreach ($files->getFiles() as $file) {
                echo "name: '".$file->getName()."' ID: '".$file->getId()."'\n";
             }
     }

    /* important step number one - get the next page token (if any) */
    $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken(); 

    /* important step number two - append the next page token to your query */
    $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
 
    $files = $google_drive_service->files->listFiles($parameters);
}
```