# google drive JS API nextpageToken invalid

Tags: javascript, api, google-drive-api

I just followed the API docs and made simple query using JS API
and getting an error 400: **Invalid Value**  of the nextPageToken

```
gapi.load('client', function(){
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', function(){
        gapi.client.init({}
        ).then(function(){
            gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                'q'         : "name contains 'nv'",
                'pageSize'  : 10,
                'fields'    : "nextPageToken, files(id, name, webContentLink, folderColorRgb, thumbnailLink, description)",
                'orderBy'   : 'modifiedTime desc',
            }).then(function(respo){
                var token = respo.result.nextPageToken;
                gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                    'fields' : '*',
                    'pageToken' : token
                }).then(function(result){console.log(result.result);})
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Token returned from first query is ok, getting it full. 
But in the next query it's becomes wrong.

Didn't find a format for the token, so I cannot check if it's good or?!

p.s. tested developers console, getting the token and in the next query getting same error.

Answer (score 5):

I have found that the subsequent page request must have the same 'q' value of the first request to avoid getting the HTTP 400 error. For example, if the first request is:

```
   gapi.client.drive.files.list({
       'q'         : "name contains 'nv'",
       'pageSize'  : 10,
       'fields'    : "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
   }).then(function(respo){
       ...
   }
```

The subsequent request must also have the same 'q':

```
   gapi.client.drive.files.list({
       'q'         : "name contains 'nv'",
       'pageToken' : nextPageToken,
       'pageSize'  : 10,
       'fields'    : "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
   }).then(function(respo){
       ...
   }
```

Make sure to always check the validity of nextPageToken as feeding a null value on subsequent request will restart the list operation all over again.

Comment: Excellent answer. The documentation has no mention of needing to repeat the query with the same parameters. One would think passing in the token would be enough to enact the next page of results but, no, the entire parameters list *must* be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I simply don't believe this!!!

Google makes such stupid things.

The problem is that it needs to be written in next query not **pageToken**, but **nextPageToken** and it's working.

Checked couple times, it does.

In docs it's written wrong and also in their console.

Shame!

Comment: This appears to be the right answer. Even my linter tells me it's wrong but pageToken is the only one that doesn't make it throw an error at runtime. Good catch. Very annying.

Answer (score 1):

This is the top result I have found for attempting to do pagination within a Google Drive JavaScript operation. They should just show an example on their documentation, but I could not find it there. Facebook had that example however. Anyway, to do paging in their framework:

```
//Global variable to hold token pointer
var NextPageToken = '';

function GetFiles() {
   gapi.client.drive.files.list({
     'pageSize': 25,
     'q': "mimeType contains 'image/'",
     'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
   }).then(function (response) {
              var files = response.result.files;
              // if response.result.nextPageToken exists, use it
              if (response.result.nextPageToken) {
                 NextPageToken = response.result.nextPageToken;                        
              } else {
                 NextPageToken = false;
              }
           });
    }

function GetNextSetOfImages() {
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            'pageSize': 25,
            'q': "mimeType contains 'image/'",
            'pageToken': NextPageToken,
            'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
        }).then(function (response) {
              var files = response.result.files;
              // if response.result.nextPageToken exists, use it
              if (response.result.nextPageToken) {
                 NextPageToken = response.result.nextPageToken;                        
              } else {
                 NextPageToken = false;
              }
           });
    }
```